# TypeError: Cannot set property 'employees' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm setting up a searchbar in a web app, and I've got most of it done(i.e. it's successfully finding the objects that I'm looking for), however, a dispatch at the end of the searchbar code. This is being built using Javascript, React and Redux. I'm entirely new to react, and my teams React guy is off for the week, so any help would be a massive help.

```
searchInList = (e) => {
    const { dispatch, employees } = this.props;
    const valueSearched = e.target.value;
    let currentList = [];
    let newList = [];

    if (valueSearched !== ' ') {
      currentList = employees;
      currentList.map(employeeObject => {
        Object.values(employeeObject).filter(item => {
          let itemString;
          if (typeof (item) != 'string') {
            itemString = JSON.stringify(item);
          } else {
            itemString = item;
          }
          let lc = itemString.toLowerCase();
          const filter = valueSearched.toLowerCase();

          if (lc.includes(filter)) {
            if (!newList.includes(employeeObject)) {
              newList.push(employeeObject);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      newList = employees;
    }
    console.log(newList);
    dispatch(onChangeEmployee('employees', newList));
  };
```

This should just narrow down the amount of objects being displayed (within the search terms), but it crashes and throws up this error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'employees' of undefined".

It crashes on the `dispatch(onChangeEmployee('employees', newList));` line

Comment: Does the error not indicate the specific line that it is crashing on?

Comment: It crashes on the `dispatch(onChangeEmployee('employees', newList));` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

> Cannot set property 'employees' of undefined

I can see you do something like

```
var a
a.employees='hello'
```

However, you never refer employees property of an object in the snippet presented

So the chance is high that the error is from `onChangeEmployee`

Comment: This is how onChangeEmployee looks                                                                                                                            `export const onChangeEmployee = (name, newValue) => ({
  type: ON_CHANGE_EMPLOYEE,
  payload: { name, newValue }
});`